# Why is SVN checking out a future revision number? (or is it just reporting so?)

Tags: svn, revision

I have checked with NetBeans and RapidSVN. My latest revision is 1000 (for example).

But when I do a `svn update` in my staging server, after checking out all files, I get the message **Checked out revision 1003**!! (off by 3).

How can it checkout a revision that is not there yet?! What is going on? Is the reporting wrong or, are both the previously mentioned tools hiding something?

- **Staging machine** - CentOS 5 with SVN client v1.4.2
- **Development machine** - Ubuntu 10.04 with NetBeans v6.9.1 and latest RapidSVN
- **Repository machine** - CentOS 5 with (no idea about version) SVN server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely the directory you're currently in, and how you're checking the revision number.  Your current directory may have been last modified at R 1000, so that's what it's reporting to you.  Somewhere else in your repository, someone else has performed 3 more operations, upping the global revision number to 1003.

Comment: I just investigated and that seems to be the case. How can I update to whatever the latest revision for my directory is? I can always update to a particular revision number, but can I tell it to update to the latest revision for my folder?

Comment: Just plain "svn update" inside the particular folder you care about will do the trick -- it always checks out the head revision.

Comment: Are you saying that it will show the head revision all the time (the one others have upped to), but properly checkout the latest files for my folder?.. If I do svn update from inside my folder i.e.

Comment: svn update without a "-r" option, always updates your workspace to show the latest version (HEAD) in the repository.Your own files, assuming only you have been editing them will reflect your local chanegs (if any) or in the absence of any un-committed local changes will reflect the LATEST/HEAD version in the repository. Youmay want to refer http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/index.html for more information on how subversion versioning works.

Comment: Yes. If you want to know what the last revision was where the directory was actually changed, run the "svn info" command.  That will give you the repo's global revision number (under "Revision:") and the last changed revision of the directory you're in ("Last Changed Rev:").  Hopefully this will give you some peace of mind ;-)

Comment: Oh okay. I think I got it now. Thanks for the link @Critical Skill :) Thanks a lot to Dave too :)